# Python Arrays Minimize Values

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I am trying to change the values of an array into smaller numbers like

`list = [1,3,7,3]`
into
`list = [1,2,3,2]`

I already have a few lines of code to keep it organized.

```
def sortItems(list):
    counts = collections.Counter(list)
    sortedlist = sorted(list, key=counts.get, reverse=True)
    return sortedlist
```

been crawling all over W3Schools and other forums but still unsure

Comment: What is the logic you want, why 7 becomes 3? Is it because it is the third biggest value?

Comment: yes. I am trying to change it so that 1 will become 1 3 will become 2 and 7 will become 3.

Comment: What should `[7, 1, 3, 1]` become?

Comment: It should become ``` [3,1,2,1] ``` but the sorting function will change it to ``` [1,1,2,3] ```

Comment: But then shouldn't your example state `[1, 2, 2, 3]`?

Comment: "crawling all over W3Schools" - That explains it :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [1, 3, 7, 3] 

unique_keys = set(l)

mappings = {key: val for val, key in enumerate(sorted(unique_keys), 1)}

print(list(map(mappings.get, l)))
```

Orders are preserved by the `sorted()`.

Comment: yes, I have changed that.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood. You are right! It will be better with enumerate(..., 1).

Comment: Or with pandas: `pd.Series(mylist).rank(method='dense').to_list()`

Answer (score 0):

(This answer addresses the information in the comments.)

For a performant implementation, count, sort keys, then repeat and flatmap.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import repeat

def flatmap_repeat_sort_count(xs):
    counts = Counter(xs)
    keys = sorted(counts.keys())
    return [
        x
        for i, k in enumerate(keys, start=1)
        for x in repeat(i, counts[k])
    ]
```

Example runs:

```
>>> flatmap_repeat_sort_count([1, 3, 7, 3])
[1, 2, 2, 3]

>>> flatmap_repeat_sort_count([7, 1, 3, 1])
[1, 1, 2, 3]
```